# How to Implement Category.php page title in wordpress custom template?

Tags: title

Lets say you have a custom template and you want to implement a title of Wordpress template 
for section /category/general      where general is a category name .

How to implement category page titile for this page .

I tried with

```
  <h2><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?    >"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

But this does not work as a clickable link .

Comment: Clickable link _to what_? :)

Comment: Clickable link to Post offcource. The page title should land to its post when clicked on category.php page .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the only problem here is a syntax error. Always remember to remove any spaces between the opening and closing tags - otherwise your code will fail.

Example:

```
<h2>
    <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</h2>
```

Make sure to read the Wordpress Codex about `the_title_attribute()` to understand better on how to customize this function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link to the current post inside the loop, you need to provide respective URL in the markup.

In your snippet `href="#"` should probably be `href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"`.